# How to add image in HTML from a link?

Tags: html, image, src

I would like to add the image present at this link http://startup.registroimprese.it/isin/search?0-IResourceListener-data-resultRow-22-resultViewPnl-companyCardContainer-logoImg&antiCache=1628599295826 to my html page. Therefore, I have added the above URL to the "src" attribute in the < img> tag. My HTML code looks like this:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<img src="http://startup.registroimprese.it/isin/search?0-IResourceListener-data-resultRow-26-resultViewPnl-companyCardContainer-logoImg&antiCache=1628599295828">

</body>
</html>
```

However, the image is not displayed when I render the page, and this is what I see.

[blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2knI.png)

What I expect to see instead, is the image at the link correctly displayed on my html page. Any idea what is wrong and how I could fix it?

NOTE: I know I could download the image locally and then add it, but I specifically need to find a solution to add the image from the link, and not from a path on my local computer.

Comment: That link says "oops, sorry. please return to home page or contact us for information and assistance" for me. I can only assume that the service at http://startup.registroimprese.it/ requires e.g. cookies (and only supports same-site cookies, maybe?)

Comment: Your link to the image must have an extension (.jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png). here is an example: https://dummyimage.com/600x450/000/fff.jpg

Comment: @AKX I have cleared cache and now I get the same error message.

Comment: @AnnaDiNardo I figured that'd happen. That means you can't hotlink images from that service, so unfortunately you can't do what you'd want here. :(

Comment: @UtmostCreator I got the link by copying the src on the page itself, which doesn't seem to have an extension at the end

Comment: @UtmostCreator There's no need for an image link to have an extension. The browser doesn't care for the URL, it's just looking at the `Content-Type` header returned by the server.

Comment: @AKX, could you please explain how did you manage to figure that out? By taking a look at the response, or what way have you used it? Did this service disable the CORS or somethings else? I would appreciate nice hearing from you an in-depth explanation.

Comment: @UtmostCreator - if simply navigating to the URL OP linked leads to a redirect to the service's index page, it's likely those assets are protected.